# Find Control - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to implement a Find Control on my page, finding a textbox with the ID "w1test", however I keep receiving an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." however I think everything is in order...

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub getTextbox()
    Try
        Dim txtbox As TextBox = CType(Page.FindControl("w1test"), TextBox)
        txtbox.Text = "UPDATED"
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show aspx page code..?

Comment: witest is present on the aspx page or it is a dynamicaly genrated control ?

Comment: No it's not dynamically generated, and there is a textbox with the ID w1test:

    <asp:TextBox ID="w1test" runat="server" Text="x"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: You need a recursive search. Look here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl

Comment: pls post your aspx code as the structure within is very important for your question!

Comment: Make sure that the event is registered in the pagename.designer.vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive version of FindControl. Something like this

```
Public Function RecursiveFindControl(container As Control, name as String) as Control
    If Not(container.ID Is Nothing) AndAlso (container.ID.Equals(name)) Then
        Return container
    End If

    For Each c as Control in container.Controls
        Dim ctrl as Control = RecursiveFindControl(c, name)
        If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
            return ctrl
        End If
    Next
    return Nothing
End Function
```

Call with

```
 Dim txtbox As TextBox = CType(RecursiveFindControl(Page, "w1test"), TextBox)
```

Comment: This did it, I'm guessing it needed to be recursive because of the master page? Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: You need to be recursive because FindControl searches only the page's immediate, or top-level, container. It does not recursively search for controls in naming containers contained on the page. Probably your control is not contained directly on the Page but in a "child" container of the page. So you need to search every control and check if it contains child controls and so on. Beware, if you have many controls on the page, this recursion could be very costly in term of performance.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. If I need to iterate over controls (for e.g. TextBox0, TextBox1, etc.) I just get the `NamingContainer` from one of these controls and the use that "parent" control to perform search for other controls as follows.

```
// get NamingContainer from one of the controls
Control parent = TextBox0.NamingContainer;
// now can iterate through controls
for(int i = 0; i < someBound; i++)
{
    ((TextBox)parent.FindControl("TextBox" + i)).Text = "Text here now";
}
```